# TFS2008 What is the difference between "Undo Pending Changes" & "Unshelve Pending Changes" exactly?

Tags: tfs-power-tools

I was wondering:

In TFS2008 What is the difference between "Undo Pending Changes" & "Unshelve Pending Changes" exactly?

Since I have upgraded to the new TFS2012 power tools I no longer can "Undo Pending Changes" on our old tfs2008 instance. But it still gives the option for "Unshelve Pending Changes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VERY VERY different.

Undo means you have checked something out, and may have made a change, but instead of checking it in, you are going to throw it out; erase it; delete it - AKA do not push this button unless you really really mean it.

To unshelve pending changes you have to have previously shelved some changes. Shelving means that you are saving them for later, leaving a copy of them where they can be retrieved if needed. So unshelving means that you are getting that copy back in your work space.

If you can no longer undo pending changes, hopefully that just means that you don't have any changes pending.

Comment: I don't think there are any "Shelved Changes", the file is just "checked out". Does this option apply in any way to a file that does not have anything "shelved" but is just "checked out" ?

Comment: You can also unshelve changes that other people have shelved. Could it be that someone else has shelved changes. You can safely click on unshelve and see what the options are, because it won't do anything until you choose a specific changeset to unshelve. Also, I'm not sure, but it may be that the unshelve option shows up even if the shelf is empty. You can probably still look at the shelf; it's just... a lot less interesting.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question what happens in the situation when you have retrieved a shelveset.  Now you no longer want it.   You want to go back to what is in the main branch.   At this point, do you unshelve your shelveset or do you undo your changes.   Both work I think.

Comment: @zumalifeguard It does answer your question and both absolutely do not work the same. Ever. Unshelving = retrieving a shelfset. So when you have already retrieved something, unshelving is no longer a relevant option for those pending changes. Undo is what you are looking for. Or, shelving it to a new shelfset (choose the option to not preserve changes locally in this case). If in this case you choose to Unshelve, you will be looking at additional shelfsets that you can retrieve, or you could retrieve that same one fresh again if you had since changed it.